# select top x strings from existing linq list

Tags: c#, linq

I want a new query to display top 10(if there even is 10 CostCenters), add the number of quantity of the string's occurence and create a new list of CostCenter(when it's grouped like this).

---

```
var xxx = (from t in _list_Costs
                           group t by new { t.Date.Year, t.Date.Month }
                               into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   Year = g.Select(o => o.Date.Year).First(),
                                   Month = g.Select(n => n.Date.Month).First(),
                                   Costs = g.Sum(n => (Decimal)n.Amount),
                                   CostCenter = g.Select(n => n.CostCenter)
                               }).ToList();
```

The result should be like:

```
Year: Month: CostCenter: Quantity:
2015 1       Bananas     5
2015 1       Apples      3
2015 2       Bananas     12
2015 2       Apples      6
2015 2       Lizzards    2
```

Comment: What do you think is going wrong?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want something like this with `orderby` and `take`:

```
CostCenter = g.Select(n => n.CostCenter).OrderBy(n => n.SomeField).Take(10)
```

Comment: I'm a big newbie in programming but I'll try to explain. :)
I want to view the top CostCenter(string) and occurrence(int) by every year and month from the "xxx"-list. 
I've added the occurence in the main question.